# How to restore the missing mysql db schema?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My DB schema is missing/deleted by someone without my knowledge from ASW EC2 windows machine. Seems some unauthorized user entered into the system illegally and did something. Since I can find some one tried multiple times to connect my DB and got failed with different usernames from the same IP address. Its recorded in the log. I couldn't find the files in Data folder related to my schema. I guess it is also deleted.

Still do we have a way to recover it and restore the dump?

I lost the data completely so not able to process anything.

Comment: Restore from a backup, and firewall your MySQL off from the public internet in the future.

Comment: @ceejayoz, Thanks. But its my mistake I didn't take the latest dump

Comment: [D'oh](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/doh)!